# How to handle Blurred images of MATLAB when copying from pdf to Word

Tags: image, matlab, pdf, pdf-generation, matlab-figure

When I copy Matlab figures by going on edit and paste into word file for some labeling and editing purposes, later for pasting images back to word file, I convert it to pdf and then take the snapshot. Additionaly to retain quality of pdf I use irfanview, as discussed in the video link attached
https://youtu.be/302i42vRi0U

The image quality is still blurred.

Can anyone please guide how to retain quality of matlab figures in doing so?

Comment: This sounds like an overcomplicated workflow... Basically, you (i) create the image in MATLAB, (ii) `print()` it to a PDF file, (iii) render the file with a PDF viewer, (iv) take a snapshot of the bitmap image, (v) send the result to Irfanview and (vi) finally to MS Word, where (vii) you carry out some "labeling and editing"?? Could you please clarify the exact sequence of operations you perform and attach any relevant code and images?

Comment: _"Additionaly to retain quality of pdf I use irfanview"_ What does it mean and why is it necessary? In what exact step is the image blurred? I assume Word doesn't support your file format and converts it. AFAIK Word doesn't support most vector graphic formats.

Comment: if you save blur matlab images you can increase figure resolution by file > export setup > rendering and change dpi to 300